# Can someone identify this tree?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

It appears to be a kind of fig tree (perhaps similar to the fiddle leaf fig tree but without the fiddle?), although the leaf shape doesn't match. It didn't seem very appealing to eat (!), it was oozing white sap from the stem and from the fruit itself when i broke it apart.

The fruit felt like a hard sponge.

I found the tree in Israel, although, in this location there are a number of non-indigenous trees.

Here are some pictures:
[image]
[image]
[image]
(NOTE: photo of full tree was taken in March, not at the same time as the first two photos)

Comment: Something similar to Ficus macrophylla that grows in Israel? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_macrophylla

Comment: Fruit and sap are certainly reminiscent of a fig, but the leaves make me think Ericaceae. @skymningen's find of *F. macrophylla*, however, suggests to me that some figs *do* in fact have eliptic coriaceous leaves....I'll dive in to see what I find

Comment: Can you provide an image of the tree itself (demonstrating its overall growth form)? Additional images of the leaves would be helpful as would sizes of the leaves and plant overall. Thanks.

Comment: @theforestecologist I walked past the tree today, and took a photo. It should be noted that the first two photos were taken in August 2016, and the third photo was taken March 2019!